# Spring security 5: providing roles for OAuth2 authenticated users

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have existing Spring Boot application with Spring Security 5 and OAuth2 client, I've successfully configured authentication with external OAuth2 provider (GitLab, in my case).

Now I have problem with configuring authorization. I'd like to have some method that would let me write code to resolve roles for given user (either by making a call to the database or just checking hard-coded username).

I've found out that it could be achieved by using `PrincipalExtractor` and `AuthoritiesExtractor`, described in a nice [article](https://medium.com/@bvulaj/mapping-your-users-and-roles-with-spring-boot-oauth2-a7ac3bbe8e7f). However, those classes are no longer present in recent Spring Security. **What is an alternative way to achieve that, compatible with Spring Security 5?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper`

it is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities) in the official spring security documentation

And here is a code example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                    .userAuthoritiesMapper(this.userAuthoritiesMapper())
                    ...
                )
            );
    }

    private GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                if (OidcUserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority)authority;

                    OidcIdToken idToken = oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken();
                    OidcUserInfo userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();

                    // Map the claims found in idToken and/or userInfo
                    // to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities

                } else if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority)authority;

                    Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

                    // Map the attributes found in userAttributes
                    // to one or more GrantedAuthority's and add it to mappedAuthorities

                }
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}
```

There are several more examples and explanations in the spring security documentation.